# Tag cleanup: is the [paperwork] tag really necessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I just stumbled upon the tag [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) when reviewing a question and I am unsure if that tag really makes sense to keep. In many instances the tag is (IMHO) misused for questions related to (scientific) papers instead of paperwork.

In the few other instances where it kind of makes sense, it is (again IMHO) not really necessary.

Should we

a) delete the tag

b) remove the tag from the questions where it is used incorrectly and see if it is worth keeping for the rest of the questions?

c) leave everything as it is?

Comment: Marking this as completed, since any pending action items are now on the other post (linked).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for finding this. I agree almost all of those questions are mistagged; we should fix this at least.

I hesitate to just nuke the tag, because there are two possible legit uses:

- organizing physical and digital papers
- dealing with bureaucracy

So, I suspect we should choose option B and also consider renaming or redefining the “paperwork” tag

Comment: I started the process of removing the tag where is used incorrectly, once finished lets have a look what the rest of the questions look like and think about renaming or redefinig from there.

Comment: Perhaps a rename to e.g. `bureaucracy` would clear the intended usage up?

Answer (score 0):

The tag only has six questions so should be easy to just cleanup. I think a tag with a better name, for such things as administrative process would be worth keeping. Maybe there is already such a tag. If not, I don't have a name at the moment. Maybe bureaucracy.

Organizing papers is a different concept that might need a separate tag if there are enough examples at the moment. Some questions on the site are about recommendations for "personal process", but research process seems to cover that idea.

But "as is" it is terrible, I agree.

Comment: To be clear, there were 25+ questions when this was posted. OP has been quick to cull the worst ones (and I deleted a few that are no longer needed).

Comment: @cag51, thanks. I got into it late.

Comment: Now we're down to two, so it seems a decision has already been taken.