# Rename tag [paperwork] and create new tag for "organizing/structuring" files, papers etc

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is a follow-up to: [Is the paperwork tag really necessary?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/tag-cleanup-is-the-paperwork-tag-really-necessary?cb=1)

After removing the tag [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) from questions where the tag was misused I had a look at the remaing questions and other questions as well.

I suggest the follwing: change the name of the tag from [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) to [bureaucracy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bureaucracy) as that lies at the heart of said paperwork, also there are several other questions not previously in the [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) where such a tag would fit well. Of course the wiki entry would have to be slightly changed as well.

On top of that, I noticed there are quite of few questions about structuring and organizing files, paper, bibliography etc. that do not really have a good tag that fits. I propose to create a new tag for that but I am unable to find a suitable, succinct phrase for such a tag as "organizing" doesn't really fit 100%. What do you think of this proposal?

Comment: As there are the most votes for the question (with suggestions how to proceed), does that imply that this is the solution we are going to go with? I am happy to implement the changes suggested.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little unclear how to interpret the outcome here. Of the 6 remaining questions, I think 3 are still mistagged, 2 are about organizing physical or digital papers, and 1 would be a suitable candidate for the "bureaucracy" tag, if we decide to make one. Perhaps untagging the three remaining mistags is the place to start.

Comment: Looks like this has been resolved [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/). Thanks for the work!

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see a need for a [bureaucracy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bureaucracy) tag, so I'd suggest just getting rid of the last instances of [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork). While, as Dr. Leonard McCoy said, "the bureaucratic mentality is the only constant in the universe", it takes different forms in different contexts and places. As such, tags such as [administration](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administration) and ones based on the type of job or location seem more appropriate in most cases. Admittedly, [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56146/17254) might be an exception. Arguably, there are also some questions about record keeping that might qualify as [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) but not necessarily [bureaucracy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bureaucracy): [example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/154146/17254).

Answer (score -3):

I would be inclined to just redefine the [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) description such that it covers both:

- organizing physical and digital papers
- dealing with bureaucracy (defined here to mean low-level administrative tasks like filling out forms and getting approvals signed).

The latter has some overlap with [administration](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administration), but not too much I think.

Comment: A tag with two different meanings, very clearly disjoint, is not a good idea in my mind.

Comment: Since the tag only has four questions, I seriously doubt it would be much of an issue. But I acknowledge that the other answer has carried the day here.