# Update: tag [paperwork] can be deleted - new tag [document-organization] created

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is a [follow-up of this question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/rename-tag-paperwork-and-create-new-tag-for-organizing-structuring-files-pa) about how to proceed with the tag [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork). Sorry for the series of questions, but as every one of them is slightly different I thought it best to create a new one.

I have now deleted the tag [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) in all instances where it was mistagged. Following Anyon's upvoted answer that a tag [bureaucracy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bureaucracy) should not be created, I retagged some of them where bureaucracy would fit with [administration](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administration), as they actually also are about administration issues, so I think that is a good alternative. There is now no question left with the tag [paperwork](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork), so I guess it can be deleted.

As per my suggestion to create a new tag for organizing papers, articles etc. I have also created the new tag [document-organization](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-organization) which I think is an OK name for that - please suggest different names if you can think of a better one. I will try to retag the questions that fit into [document-organization](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-organization) within the next days.

Comment: You should give some wiki to the new tag. You are probably the best one to do so since you've looked at all of these recently.

Comment: @Buffy I already wrote a short description, but it has to be reviewed first before it will be visible. I will also add a more detailed wiki entry soon.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that a better name for this tag might be document-organization. I added some wiki to indicate that the tag shouldn't be used for filing complaints or applications, but the name is currently likely to lead to such usage.

Comment: Yes, that is a good suggestion. I will change the tag accordingly.

Comment: OK, I see that I cannot change a tag name. That will need to be done by a moderator I guess.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a mod action? If a mod changes the name I don't think it will disrupt the top question listing order. Maybe you have superpowers that I don't, but adding a new tag and retagging is probably not the best way to do it.

Comment: I think we wrote the comment at the same time: I (sadly) don't actually have superpowers and thus did not change anything.

Comment: Go to the Ivory Tower and ping one of the mods to look at it. And, thanks for all the "maintenance" you do on this site.

Comment: @Sursula I've renamed the tag, thanks for the tag maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

I've renamed the tag, so that we can consider this [status-completed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).

About the deletion of the older tag, mods can't directly delete tags, but as explained in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/300001) on the main Meta, *tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day*.